# Python integration of Objects in others

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, object, model-view-controller

**fix:** I moved an invoke of a Radiobutton from the init of my view to the controller like this:

```py
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        print('start init of View')
        self.view = View(self.importieren, self.exportieren, self.beenden, self.J5, self.J6, self.J7, self.J8, self.J9,
                         self.J10, self.J11, self.J12, self.JA, self.tabelle_sorti, self.hinzufugen, self.zuordnen,
                         self.ande, self.JA, self.model.ausgabe('projekte'), self.tabelle_update, self.a1, self.a2, self.a3,
                         self.a4, self.a5, self.a6, self.a7)
        print('done init')
        self.wahlen = ('sErst', 'sZweit', 'sDritt')
        self.delimiter = {'imp_s': None, 'imp_p': None, 'exp': None}
        self.dchosen = None
        self.slcsv = 'schuelerliste.csv'
        self.plcsv = 'projektliste.csv'
        self.double = False
        self.andernx = ""

        self.view.radios['jahrg-Alle'].invoke()
        self.tabelle()
        self.view.table['main'].bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.treevent)
        # Erstimportierung
        if self.model.ausgabe('schueler'):
            self.importieren(True)

        self.view.mainloop()


    def tabelle_update(self, fetchshlr=None, fetchprj=None):
        print('start update')
        if fetchshlr is None:
            fetchshlr = self.model.ausgabe('schueler')
        if fetchprj is None:
            fetchprj = self.model.ausgabe('projekte')

        self.view.tableup(fetchshlr, fetchprj)
```

This invoke called the function, before View was ready and so caused the error. Thanks for the Help

I tried to not ask a question hear, but after hours of searching I have to.
I am currently working on a programm and recently splitted the main file in three in style of the MVC-Scheme. And I have one function to update a Treeview working as a table. But this function (and only that one!), says:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback\
Traceback (most recent call last):\
  File "C:\Users\...\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__\
    return self.func(*args)\
  File "C:/Users/.../Controller.py", line 184, in tabelle_update\
    self.view.table['main'].tag_configure(i[0], background='white')\
AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'view'
```

I already tried to use lambda (and if you ask why, because someone said it in the internet) and it just prevented the function to work at all. Also I think it has something todo with this:

```py
{'model': <Model.Model object at 0x0000018CA8068160>, 'view': <View.View object .>, ...}
```

this is an extract of the attributes ditionary and I think it has something to do with the missing at 0x... part in 'view' as seen in 'model'
Please Help me to get this up and running

And here are my important code parts (if you need more, pls write)
**note that the diffrent classes are in diffrent files and are properly imported**

**Major Changes in programmcode under tabelle_update and under the View class tableup**
I tried to move the View heavy parts to View, didn't fix anything.

```py
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View(self.importieren, self.exportieren, self.beenden, self.J5, self.J6, self.J7, self.J8, self.J9,
                         self.J10, self.J11, self.J12, self.tabelle_update, self.tabelle_sorti, self.hinzufugen,
                         self.zuordnen, self.ande, self.tabelle_update, self.model.ausgabe('projekte'),
                         self.tabelle_update, self.a1, self.a2, self.a3, self.a4, self.a5, self.a6, self.a7)
        self.wahlen = ('sErst', 'sZweit', 'sDritt')
        self.delimiter = {'imp_s': None, 'imp_p': None, 'exp': None}
        self.dchosen = None
        self.slcsv = 'schuelerliste.csv'
        self.plcsv = 'projektliste.csv'
        self.double = False
        self.andernx = ""

        self.tabelle()
        self.view.table['main'].bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.treevent)
        # Erstimportierung
        if self.model.ausgabe('schueler'):
            self.importieren(True)

        print(self.__dict__)

        self.view.mainloop()
    
    def tabelle(self):
        fetch = self.model.ausgabe('schueler')
        self.view.shlr_tabelle(fetch)

    def tabelle_update(self, fetchshlr=None, fetchprj=None):
        print('start update')
        if fetchshlr is None:
            fetchshlr = self.model.ausgabe('schueler')
        if fetchprj is None:
            fetchprj = self.model.ausgabe('projekte')

        self.view.tableup(fetchshlr, fetchprj)

class View(ttkthemes.ThemedTk):
    def __init__(self, imp, exp, bee, j5, j6, j7, j8, j9, j10, j11, j12, ja, tabsort, hin, zord, ande, scht,
                 prjt, aktutable, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7):
        # print(ttkthemes.THEMES)   # zum Ausgeben der verfügbaren Themes
        ttkthemes.ThemedTk.__init__(self, theme='breeze')
        self.title("Projektwochenverwaltungsprogramm")
        self.geometry('800x300')
        self.minsize(800, 300)
        self.resizable(width=True, height=True)

        # bestimmen der Callbacks
        self.callback_imp = imp
        self.callback_exp = exp
        self.callback_bee = bee
        self.radiocom = {'jahrg': [j5, j6, j7, j8, j9, j10, j11, j12, ja], 'ande': [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7]}
        self.tabelle_sorti = tabsort
        self.callback_aktut = aktutable
        self.callback_zord = zord
        self.callback_hin = hin
        self.callback_ande = ande
        self.callback_scht = scht
        self.callback_prjt = prjt


        # Tabelle
        self.scrollbars = {'main': Scrollbar(self.rahmen[2], orient="vertical")}
        self.table = {'main': Treeview(self.rahmen[2], yscrollcommand=self.scrollbars['main'].set, height=200)}
        self.scrollbars['main'].pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

        self.rahmen[1].pack()
        self.rahmen['popup_pro'].pack(fill=X)
        self.rahmen[2].pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)


    def shlr_tabelle(self, fetch):
        ml = ['ID']
        for name in self.names['schueler']:
            ml.append(name)
        ml.append('Zugeordned zu')
        self.table['main']['columns'] = ml
        self.table['main']['show'] = 'headings'
        for i in range(len(ml)):
            self.table['main'].column(ml[i], width=self.width['schueler'][i], minwidth=self.width['schueler'][i])
        for i in range(len(ml)):
            self.table['main'].heading(ml[i], text=ml[i], command=lambda col=i: self.tabelle_sorti(col, False, 'main'))
        for t in fetch:
            self.table['main'].insert('', t[0], t[0], values=t)  # , tags=t[0]
        self.scrollbars['main'].config(command=self.table['main'].yview)
        self.table['main'].pack(fill=BOTH)

    def prj_tabelle(self, fetch):
        self.top['prjt'] = Toplevel()
        self.top['prjt'].title('Projekte Liste')
        self.top['prjt'].geometry('800x300')
        self.top['prjt'].minsize(800, 300)
        self.scrollbars['prj'] = Scrollbar(self.top['prjt'], orient="vertical")
        self.table['prj'] = Treeview(self.top['prjt'], yscrollcommand=self.scrollbars['prj'].set, height=200)

        ml = ['ID']
        for name in self.names['projekte']:
            ml.append(name)
        self.table['prj']['columns'] = ml
        self.table['prj']['show'] = 'headings'
        for i in range(len(ml)):
            self.table['prj'].column(ml[i], width=self.width['projekte'][i], minwidth=self.width['projekte'][i])
        for i in range(len(ml)):
            self.table['prj'].heading(ml[i], text=ml[i], command=lambda col=i: self.tabelle_sorti(col, False, 'prj'))
        for t in fetch:
            self.table['prj'].insert('', t[0], t[0], values=t)  # , tags=t[0]
        self.scrollbars['prj'].config(command=self.table['prj'].yview)
        self.scrollbars['prj'].pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)
        self.table['prj'].pack(fill=BOTH)

    def tableup(self, fetchshlr, fetchprj):
        print('läuft')
        for i in fetchshlr:
            self.view.table['main'].tag_configure(i[0], background='white')
        self.view.table['main'].delete(*self.view.table['main'].get_children())

        for t in fetchshlr:
            self.view.table['main'].insert('', t[0], t[0], values=t)  # , tags=t[0]

        for ele in fetchshlr:
            if ele[8] is None:
                self.view.table['main'].tag_configure(ele[0], background='#fa6150')

        try:
            for i in fetchprj:
                self.view.table['prj'].tag_configure(i[0], background='white')
            self.view.table['prj'].delete(*self.view.table['prj'].get_children())

            for t in fetchprj:
                self.view.table['prj'].insert('', t[0], t[0], values=t)  # , tags=t[0]

            failed = self.model.prj_aktu()
            for prj in failed:
                self.view.table['prj'].tag_configure(prj, background='#fa6150')
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: One thing that would make your code much easier to understand, debug, and maintain is to do something like `self.view = View(controller=self)`, and then inside the view use `self.controller` to access all of the elements of the controller (eg: `self.controller importieren`, `self.controller.a5`, etc). There's no reason to pass each of the attributes individually.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but that isn't something I can do, because I was given the task to do it like I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ask yourself when `self.view` is fully initialized, and when you're trying to access `self.view`. The error is telling you that you're trying to access it before you define it.

You should be able to visualize this by adding print statements like so:

```
print("before self.view is defined")
self.view = View(...)
print("after self.view is defined")
```

and then:

```
print("using self.view...")
self.view.table['main'].tag_configure(i[0], background='white')
```

Comment: I just tried that, although I think it is impossible to run a function with the GUI befor the GUI is even there, at the only point where the command is run without the GUI: (to be seen in the main thread, because the comment is to short) and got that error:

Comment: sorry gotta take back what I just said, but now this happens:
`start init of View\n
start update\n
done init\n` and it seems like its doing the error run in the init phase, but I wouldn't know, why it would be executed there. The only other functions who are executed in the init are importieren(True) and tabelle(), but lastly doesn't run tabelle_update() and in the other one but a marker, so a print statement, and it didn't show up, so wasn't executed.